# jQuery - Populate closest hidden input with radio's value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML and jQuery to populate hidden fields within each `<td>` element:

```
<td>
    <div id="sex_div" style="text-align: left; width:120;">
        <input type="hidden" id="sex" value=""/>
        <input type="radio" id="sex_male" name="sex_div" value="M"/><label for="sex_male">Male</label>
        <input type="radio" id="sex_female" name="sex_div" value="F"/><label for="sex_female">Female</label>
    </div>
</td>
```

The jQuery I have is as follows:

```
$("input :radio").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings("input [type='hidden']").val($(this).val());
});
```

and obviously the buttonset,

```
$("#sex_div").buttonset();
```

This is just a small part of the whole form. The rest all looks similar. 
Now the issue is that the hidden field is not being set when clicking/selecting a radio button. I have been struggling with this seemingly easy problem for two days now!

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(this).siblings("input[type='hidden']").val($(this).val());
```

There should be no space between `input` and `[type='hidden']`. Spaces in selectors mean to search for descendant elements that match the next token.

Comment: A space... Seriously! Thanks for that, never knew that spaces meant something else entirely!

Answer (score 1):

you need to remove space in your selector

```
$("input:radio").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings("input[type='hidden']").val($(this).val());
});
```